# AWS AutoScaling CPUUtilization metric not accurate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu-usage, autoscaling

I do heavy computation on incoming data traffic, similar to web server requests but not exactly. The computation uses mainly cpu. Memory or disk read/write is hardly used at all. I deployed this application to an autoscaling group. I also have some customised measurements on the performance of the system, beside the default AWS AutoScaling CPUUtilization metrics.

The strange thing I found out is, sometimes the default AWS AutoScaling CPUUtilization metrics can be as high as 95%, but my customised measurements show that the system works just fine, as also justified by my visual user check.

I'm quite confident on my customised measurements and I believe that it really shows the true performance. But should I consider the high CPUUtilization in this case as abnormal, and it's just simply not accurate?

Comment: "CPUUtilization metrics can be as high as 95%, but my customised measurements show that the system works just fine" - 95% CPU utilization doesn't mean that your application isn't "fine" - it just means that you're close to the limit, and in case you'll hit that limit - your application might suffer from performance degradation. Further, you don't provide enough information: what do you consider as "fine", how do you measure ? what does the "visual check" includes ? etc.

Comment: It's a company project so I can't disclose so much. I just give a comparable example. Let's say it's a video streaming site, CPU load is around 95%, but when you watch the clip on the site, it just shows smoothly. That's what I meant for "fine" and "visual check".

Comment: I think my asking is more gathering feedback from anyone who is used to operate the system at this high CPU load level, whether it's ok to be like that or should I take any precautions?